What were Mr. Reed's motives, and how was he going to achieve them?
In Heretic (2024), what were Mr. Reed's motives and how was he going to achieve them (i.e., what was his original plan had the "prophet" not gone off script)? I consider this to be one question, as the why and the how appear to be strongly connected for the character.
The parts that I found somewhat confusing in this regard are:

He could not have predicted that the church's elder would appear on his doorstep, ring the bell, and distract the girls, making switching out the corpse possible without getting noticed. Even if he would have anticipated the elder showing up at some point to look for the missing girls, he certainly could not have predicted exactly when that would occur. So, how was he originally going to distract the girls to perform his magic trick?

Even if the magic trick would have worked out as planned and convinced the girls that they witnessed an actual "miracle," then what? Would he have expected them to just submit to him because of that demonstration? Would he have locked them in cages just like the others and moved on to luring in the "next batch"?

Why is he trying to "recruit," possess, and control girls in the first place? Is his goal simply to have people around who worship him? Or is he just trying to prove his point ("control is the only real religion")—but then, once his victims are broken and submissive (or even killed themselves), there's not much left to prove as there is no longer any resistance to prove against.



I revised the question and removed the one item that could be considered to be too broad or off-topic. It's really just one question: What does Mr. Reed want and what was his plan? (both are undoubtedly connected). Items 1-3 are provided as context as to why I'm questioning / wondering about both motives and plan. Let me know if you think it is focused enough now.

The question seems focused enough in its current revision.

@gingerbreadboy Could you elaborate on what led you to conclude it's "impossible to know"? What sources have you consulted? If you've conducted research on this topic, please share your findings in an answer.

@gingerbreadboy I'd say it's way too early to draw that conclusion - the movie has just been released, and afaict there are currently no additional resources available (deleted scenes, behind the scenes, scripts, interviews, etc.) which could yield further information in the future. Also, for a movie as rich in terms of imagery and religious references as this one, I'd actually be really surprised if there weren't any deeper/hidden clues to its plot and characters.

The question "What does Mr. Reed want and what was his plan [to achieve this]?" requires two distinct answers. In addition you're asking after three specific aspects of this overarching question, the first two of which can probably only be answered with out-of-universe reasoning ("he knew because the script required him to").

Mr. Reed's primary motive was to prove his hypothesis that "control is the one true religion." He has spent his life studying various religious systems, not out of spiritual curiosity but to validate his cynical hypothesis that all faiths are merely tools for men to manipulate and control others. His encounter with Sister Barnes and Paxton is a calculated experiment to test this theory.
As co-director Bryan Woods explains in the Den of Geek "Heretic Ending Explained by the Filmmakers" article:

Mr. Reed has spent his entire life investigating what is the one true religion... And over the course of his life, he has come to a hypothesis that he believes that the one true religion is control. So every religion is just really essentially men contriving a system to communicate their beliefs and operate and control how people live their lives and control how they think.

Regarding your specific questions:

Reed's original plan did not rely on the church elder's unexpected appearance. According to Woods, Reed operated with multiple decision-tree plans, like a chess player thinking several moves ahead:


Mr. Reed has in his experiments of control, and his hypothesis of 'I can control somebody with ideologies and thoughts,' would have kind of decision-treed out multiple outcomes for this evening... Many, many different outcomes. And as the night progresses, he has to keep going back to 'okay, so this happened, so I think they'll do this if I do that. So I’m gonna go over here and do this thing.’ … It’s  almost like a game to him, hence the model kind of house, it’s like a chessboard. And he’s constantly playing chess in his mind. He’s predicting what they’re going to do and what he’s going to do.


Interestingly, Reed didn't initially plan to harm Sisters Barnes and Paxton at all. Woods reveals:


So he’s testing his hypothesis on this night, and there was a 98 percent chance on this night that the movie takes place on where he would have talked to these two missionaries and then would have sent them on their merry way. They basically would have had some awkward conversation in the living room, and then he would have said goodbye, they would have left. That was the most likely outcome of this evening. […]

      What changed his plans was Sister Barnes's defiance. As Sophie Thatcher (who plays Barnes) explains:

I think there's possibly a threatening quality to her, because she is the first one to question him... And I think maybe he's not quite as used to that and is thrown off.

      And as Woods explains:

However, as the evening progresses, Reed finds himself intrigued and threatened by Sister Barnes. He thinks that she is quite the sparring partner and he is excited by her intelligence, and eventually that intelligence gets out of control and becomes dangerous for him. And so in order to maintain control, he has to cross a line.


Reed's goal is not to have worshippers but to prove his intellectual dominance. As for his broader motivation for recruiting and controlling girls, the article suggests that Reed sees himself as conducting experiments to prove his thesis about control being the ultimate religion. He specifically targets religious missionaries to challenge and break down their faith, attempting to prove that his intellectual control can overcome their spiritual beliefs.

However, his plan ultimately fails because he underestimates Barnes and Paxton.
Mr. Reed's motives revolve around his desire to control and prove his intellectual superiority. His original plan involved elaborate mind games and distractions to achieve this control. However, his inability to fully predict and control the actions of Sister Barnes and Sister Paxton ultimately leads to his downfall, highlighting the limitations of his hypothesis.

Nice find, that's the kind of background info I was hoping for. The plot still leaves a few things to be desired, e.g. I still can't imagine how Mr. Reed could have effectively distracted Barnes and Paxton without the "help" of the elder.

@Fonic Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed the numbering. As for Mr. Reed,  I believe he's improvising as he goes along, in line with the chess metaphor.
